# OpenCL: Is there a reliable way to find the number of shader cores available on a given device?

Tags: opencl, shader

CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS doesn't seem to return the number of shaders ("compute unit" != "shader core" apparently).

Is CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE (a) guaranteed, (b) likely or (c) unlikely to be the same as the number of shaders?

I ask because I need to scan the list of available devices and assess which is likely to be the"best" for GPGPU - I can't think of a better criterion than CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY * number of shaders.

Thanks

Comment: "best" depends on everything, Even a pci-e bottleneck can make most core device slowest. Simple way would be not query but benchmark some code, especially the code itself that is to be run. Closest thing to query is number of compute units and that is irrelevant there are intel amd nvidia in same machine or even different series of nvidia in same machine. But there is a gtx970 and a gtx980, number of compute units can give hint about expected performance but if 980 is on a pci-e 1x and 970 on a pci-e 16x then processing N images can be slower on 980.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. I don't wish to deduce which is the fastest device on my hardware (obviously I know, and I if I didn't, I would benchmark it). I am writing desktop software which can run anywhere, and I need a simple query to determine which device is likely to be "best" on the user's system (best = more gflops). Benchmarking their PC before running the software seems like overkill. PCI-e isn't particularly relevant here, the OpenCL kernels are processor bound, not i/o bound.

Comment: Then you should look at CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_SIZE since cache size is incremented for bigger gpus and helps cores yield more percentage of maximum gflops value of gpu.